# Get delta value of Multifield

Tags: 7, views, entities, theming

How do I get the delta value of a multifield in a View template? I need to get the delta value in the Row output View template.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($row->field_my_field as $data): ?>

  <?php if ($data['raw']['value'] == 'o'): ?>
    // Output nothing, or placeholder, whatever
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php print $data['rendered']['#markup']; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```